# Error Aplicación Formula ErlangC - TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
TasaServicio    Cajeros
0   19.8           1    
1   19.8           1    
2   19.8           1    
3   19.8           1    
4   19.8           1    
5   19.8           1    
6   19.8           1    
7   19.8           1    
8   19.8           1    
9   19.8           1    
10  19.8           1    
11  19.8           1    
12  19.8           1    
13  19.8           1    
14  19.8           1    
15  19.8           1    
16  19.8           1    
17  19.8           1    
18  19.8           1    
19  19.8           1    
20  19.8           1    
21  19.8           1    
22  19.8           1    
23  19.8           1
```

Quisiera crear una nueva columna donde se aplique la siguiente función ErlangC:

```
from scipy.special import factorial
def ErlangC(k, r):
    
    H = np.array(list(r))
    I = np.array(list(k))
    A = np.power(I,H)
    B = factorial(H)
    C = np.subtract(H,I)
    D = np.divide(H,C)
    E = np.divide(A,B)
    L = E * D
    sum_ = 0
    for i in H:
        F = np.power(k,i)
        sum_ += F / factorial(i)
    return (L / (sum_ + L))
```

Asi estoy invocando la función

```
df['C(k,r)'] = df.apply(lambda x: ErlangC(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
```

El error me lo marca en la siguiente línea:

```
 2 def ErlangC(k, r):
      3 
----> 4     H = np.array(list(r))
      5     I = np.array(list(k))
      6     A = np.power(I,H)
```

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

**Quizás estoy aplicando mal la lista al integrarla a un array pero si lo elimino tendría error de 0-d array. ¿Alguna sugerencia?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por error conceptual de mi parte, ya pude obtener la respuesta. Simplemente utilce [ ] para crear una lista de un escalar.

```
    H = np.array([r])
    I = np.array([k])
```